# How to open an .exe through the Command Line in Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

I have PL/SQL Developer installed, and I am trying to get Sikuli to open it through the Command Line.

If I do it manually I do: 
1) Open CMD 
2) "C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe" 
3) [Enter]

This is my code:

```
vcCMD = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe"'
App.open('CMD ' + vcCMD)
```

It did log that the `App.open()` has runned, but the `.exe` does not open.

```
[log] App.open CMD "C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed `/C`

```
vcCMD = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe"'
App.open('CMD /C ' + vcCMD)
```

Or even more simple:

```
run(vcCMD)
```

Comment: If you use the `run` command the Sikuli IDE disappears. `App.open` allows you to create the test.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os


def firstline(x):
    wait(2)
    os.popen("@echo off")
    t="echo "+x+">log.csv"
    os.popen(t)


def append(x,y):
    wait(2)
    os.popen("@echo off")
    for i in range (0,y):
        x=","+x
        wait(1)
    t="echo "+x+">>log.csv"
    os.popen(t)


firstline("Invalid,test,test1")
append("test1",0)
append("test2",1)
append("test3",2)
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this to another question? It doesn’t appear to have anything to do with launching an executable from Sikuli.